# Integrating bootstrap-select to work with Ember

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js

I'm trying to get [bootstrap-select](https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select) working with Ember.js. Something about Ember's management of view objects that prevents it from working as intended.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheWorkerAnt/8d2Me/1/)**

`$("select").selectpicker()` works okay for normal selects, and replaces Ember.Select views HTML but the Ember ones are broken.

The `.ember-view` class is what's responsible here and you can hack it to remove that class from the select and options to make bootstrap-select work, but then of course ember no longer pays attention to it, defeating the purpose.

Anyone understand EmberView enough to make this work? Should I try and override Ember.Select? Or does bootstrap-select need changing? I'm adrift in a sea of source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working in current production Ember.js version (1.8) and handlebars version (1.3), by simply calling `selectpicker()` in view's `didInsertElement` function

```
didInsertElement: function(){
    $("#selectPicker").selectpicker()
}
```

For examplee see 
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/drGYf/8/).

In earlier versions of Ember it probably did not work due to the way handlebar templates were rendered.

Answer (score 10):

This is not the bootstrap select component but the [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) (much nicer :) and this is how we have set it up to play nicely with the ember select view:

```
App.Select2SelectView = Ember.Select.extend({
  prompt: 'Please select...',
  classNames: ['input-xlarge'],

  didInsertElement: function() {
    Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, 'processChildElements');
  },

  processChildElements: function() {
    this.$().select2({
        // do here any configuration of the
        // select2 component
    });
  },

  willDestroyElement: function () {
    this.$().select2("destroy");
  }
})
```

and then we use it like so:

```
<div class="controls">
    {{view App.Select2SelectView
        id="mySelect"
        contentBinding="App.staticData"
        optionValuePath="content.id"
        optionLabelPath="content.label"
        selectionBinding="controller.selectedId"}}
</div>
```

I think although it is for the [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) component you can use the same hooks `didInsertElement` and `willDestroyElement` for the bootstrap select component.

And if you really need the bootstrap select, then maybe this is something for you: https://github.com/emberjs-addons/ember-bootstrap

Hope it helps

Comment: Haven't set this up yet but looks like just what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: This code doesn't do any updates to select2 when the data changes. Does select2 do that automatically when the select html element changes?
I tried this and the selected values changed programatically do not show up. Only those which you manually/explicitly select using the ui.

Answer (score 2):

I also added this to make select2 selection react to selectionBinding changing:

```
_underlyingSelectionDidChange: Ember.observer((function() {
   this.$().select2('val', this.$().val().toString());
}), "selection.@each");
```

Comment: good point: I did something like this:
    `selectedCategoryDidChange: function(){
      // do something with this.get('selectedCategories')
    }.observes('selectedCategories.@each')`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to look at [ember-cli-select-picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-select-picker) addon for ember. It probably not extactly what you are looking for, because bootstrap 3 dropdowns gives many possibilities for customization. But it good be a good point to look into it and take it as a start point.