# how to initialize plugin when an app is ready?

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to configure iScroll plugin. According to documentation it should load when DOM is ready. I tried with `didInsertElement` on a view but it didn't work as expected.

Unfortunately, I can't access any Ember views inside app ready hook - it returns no elements:
`foo = $('.ember-view').length === 0 // true`

When I init the plugin manually, it works.

So, how can I init additional plugins that need DOM elements rendered with handlebars?

Comment: did you take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16566700/integrating-bootstrap-select-to-work-with-ember/16568678#16568678

Answer (score 1):

The general idea is to do this in the `didInsertElement`. Say you have a jQuery plugin that needs to be run when things are in the DOM:

```
didInsertElement: function() {
   $("#selector").plugin();
}
```

This should solve your problem. Obviously, the plugin JavaScript has to be already loaded here. You should do that in the conventional way.